# Rails polymorhic comments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, polymorphic-associations

I'm building a reddit clone (just for practise)) and having a problem with a form for new comment reply. I used [this](http://kconrails.com/2010/10/23/nested-comments-in-ruby-on-rails-1-models/) tutorial for building polymorphic comments and everything works fine but I want to add forms for new comment replies just under the reply, so that you click a link and the form appears (the div with the form is hidden by default). But it seems that the form appears for each new object that I generate in my form, so It's just infinite cycle. Are there any ways for creating forms for comment replies?

Here's my _form:

```
  = form_for comment do |f|
    p
      = f.label :body
      = f.text_area :body

      = f.hidden_field :link_id, value: params[:link_id]

      - if params[:link_id]
        = hidden_field_tag :link_id, params[:link_id]
      - if params[:comment_id]
        = hidden_field_tag :comment_id, params[:comment_id]

    = f.submit "Create", class: "button tiny"
```

And the _comment partial:

```
li.comment
  p = comment.body

  p = link_to "Add a reply", "", class: "reply_link"
  .comment_form
    = render 'comments/form', comment: comment.comments.build

  - unless comment.comments.empty?
    ul.comments_list
      = render partial: 'comments/comment', collection: comment.comments
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the solution was quite simple. Rather than rendering forms for each comment, which would be quite slow, I decided to user AJAX to build forms on the fly.
Here's the _comment view:

```
- if comment.id && comment.user
  li id="comment-#{comment.id}" class="comment"
    h6 = "From #{link_to comment.user.email, user_path(comment.user)}".html_safe
    .comment_body
      = comment.body
    = render 'shared/likes_panel', object: comment
    = link_to "Reply",
      new_comment_path(comment_id: comment.id),
      remote: true
    .comment_form

    - unless comment.comments.empty?
      = render 'comments/list', comments: comment.comments
```

As you can see, in link_to I use ***remote: true***, which points to **new** action in the comments_controller which should respond to js:

```
def new
    @comment = @parent.comments.new
    @comment.user = current_user

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

And finally you'll need new.js.erb to append the comment form to the right comment:

```
var li = $("#comment-<%= params[:comment_id] %>");
li.find(".comment_form").html("<%= j render 'comments/form' %>");
```

As soon as you comments in `<ul>`, all the subcomments will be nicely indented!

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue with the following jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.partner-area').click(function() {
        $(this).next('.partner-offices').slideToggle(500);
    });
});
```

Where above, `.partner-area` is the class of the link to click on, and `.partner-offices` is the class name of my form. This is basically saying that when whatever link is clicked, the very next form will animate and open.

Default css on the form `display: hidden`

Comment: Thank you, even though it wasn't exactly what I was looking for, but you gave me the idea to use ajax for rendering the form)

Comment: Oh glad to hear it! I'd love to see your solution for my own education if you could post it?! Thanks

Comment: Add the answer, hope it will be helpful)